# Drivers for TOOYA X(graphic tablet)

Tags: drivers, 15.04

I have PenPower [TOOYA X](http://www.penpowerinc.com/product.asp?sn=686) graphic tablet.

website says, System requirements are:

- Windows 8 / Windows7 / Vista / XP
- Mac OS X 10.6 or later
- USB port

There is no  mention about Linux.

How can I use it on Ubuntu?

---

P.S. I don't have live CD

Comment: read trough this, maybe it will help you http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1103792

Answer (score 0):

See if https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom helps at all, it seemed to help the OP over [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1103792) (credit to MiHa for the link). I'd recommend you plug it into your computer and attempt to do something in System Settings > Wacom Tablet, it may properly work without any additional configuration.

Comment: I edited  xorg.conf file as shown in @MiHa's link.  Then changed input device as shown in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom. But it does not help! :-(